# Nothing happens when accessing an async task from repository in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I am creating an async task in a repo, and then accessing it from the controller to try and minimize the logic in the controller.

The thing is, that when I used the exact same logic in the controller, there was an output, now that I'm accessing this way, it isn't searching for it.

Repository:

```
   public async Task<List<Guests>> GetGuesteByAsync(string Search)
    {
        var list = GetAll();
        var listquery = from x in context.Guest select x;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Search))
        {
            listquery = listquery.Where(x => x.FullName.Contains(Search) ||  x.Organisation.Contains(Search));
        }

        return await context.Guests.ToListAsync();
    }
```

The controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string Search)
    {
ViewData["Getsearchinput"] = EmpSearch;
        //List<Guests> listofguests = await repository.GetGuesteByAsync(Search);
        var res = await (repository.GetGuesteByAsync(Search));
        return View(res);

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happens"? Does the code hang on some line? What actually happens?

Comment: The view changes the link with the search input, but the list is not updated

Comment: What list is not updated?

Comment: The list that is generated from the async method which is being called from the repository in the controller.

Comment: Which list are you checking, `var list = GetAll();` doesn't look like its used.

Comment: i am so confused here. you are getting your results in this - listquery , and, you decided to return this - return await context.Guests.ToListAsync(); I see there is an answer posted pointing this out, but why return a totally unrelated variable at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns all entries.

```
return await context.Guests.ToListAsync();
```

I think you should use your query. Can you try this?

```
return await listquery.ToListAsync();
```